# Trouble on testing a model method call in a spec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10, RSpec 2 and FactoryGirl. I am trying to validate user account data.

In my model I have:

```
class Users::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def get_account_password_salt(password)
    make_user_account_password_salt(password)
  end
end
```

In my spec file I have

```
it "should have a valid password salt" do
  users_account.password_salt.should == Users::Account.get_account_password_salt('123456')
end
```

When I run the `rspec` command I get the following error:

```
Users::Account should have a valid password salt
Failure/Error: users_account.password_salt.should == Users::Account.get_account_password_salt('123456')
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `get_account_password_salt' for #<Class:0x0000010729c9f0>
```

**What is the problem and how can I solve that?**

I also tryed to use `::Users::Account.get_account_password_salt('123456')` (note the `::` at the beginning) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @antonversal - Yes, I am sure. 'Users' is a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The problem was that I have to run

```
users_account.get_account_password_salt('123456')
```

instead of:

```
Users::Account.get_account_password_salt('123456')
```